# hardship with input from user and replace letters

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to write code that takes input from user and replace every occurrence of the first letter with the letter `e` except the first letter.
For example: `"ddar astronaut. pldase, stop drasing md!"` should be `dear astronaut. please, stop erasing me!`.

And I get `eear astronaut. please, stop erasing me`

This is my code:

```
user_input = input("Please enter a string:")
replacemnet = user_input[0]
print(replacemnet)
print(user_input[0:-1:1].replace(replacemnet, "e", -1))
```

Comment: Slice is wrong, this removes the last character. Use [1:] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str.replace(...)`'s 3th argument says how many occurences get replaces maximum.
-1 is not a valid for this argument.
what you should do is call replace on the substring you want it to work on:

```
d = "ddar astronaut. pldase, stop drasing md!"
new_d = d[0] + d[1:].replace(replacement, 'e')
```

output

```
'dear astronaut. please, stop erasing me!'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
d = "ddar astronaut. pldase, stop drasing md!"
new_d = d[0]+''.join(i if i.lower() != 'd' else 'e' for i in d[1:])
```

Output:

```
'dear astronaut. please, stop erasing me!'
```

Comment: sorry. i forget to mention, i cant use IF statements right now.

Comment: @Bitoff Then miThom's answer above is what you are looking for.

Comment: that seems like a strange constraint, any information as to why not? certainly for an if inside of the list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks ! you guys help me alot